# How to reduce this equation to the form of y == k*x + b

Tags: simplifying-expressions, algebraic-manipulation

I want to reduce this equation to the form of y == kx + b, but I cann't do that using MMA.

```
Collect[(Det[( {
       {1, x, y},
       {1, a, b},
       {1, c, d}
      } )] == 0) // FullSimplify(*Two points determine a straight line*), {x, y}]
```

Comment: Have a look at `Solve`.

Comment: I've changed my goal to y == kx + b.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try

```
Solve[Det[({{1, x, y}, {1, a, b}, {1, c, d}})] == 0, y][[1]] //Collect[#, x, Simplify] &
(*{y -> (-b c + a d)/(a - c) + ((b - d) x)/(a - c)}*)
```

create equation

```
(% /. Rule -> Equal) [[1]]
(*y == (-b c + a d)/(a - c) + ((b - d) x)/(a - c)*)
```

Comment: But it's not in the format of y = k * x + B, it needs some other operations, such as ApplySides.

Comment: I modiefied my answer...

Answer (score 1):

I solve this problem like this, but it's too complicated.

```
SolveAlways[
 Det[({{1, x, y}, {1, a, b}, {1, c, d}})] == A*y + B*x + CC && 
  k != 0, {x, y}]
Defer[(y == -(B/A)*x - CC/A == 0)] /. %
```